# Find the value for $v(x,y)$ in the function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $u(x,y)=\log(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the value for $v(x,y)$ in the function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $u(x,y)=\log(x^2+y^2)$

I used the equations of Cauchy-Riemann and become:
$v(x,y)=2 \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})+c$

The answer should be: $-2 \tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{y})+c$

What did I do wrong? To explain my solution, I uploaded a scratch.

[image]

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The problem is. It's also given that f(i)=0. In my solution I will divide by 0...

Comment: I misread the given answer, I will answer your question.

Comment: The trouble with $\arctan(y/x)$ is that it gives the same result for $(-x,-y)$. That is why some computer languages provide a two argument arctan such as $\arctan(x,y)$ for this reason. An alternative function is $\arctan(y/x) = 2 \arctan(y/(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}))$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\, f(x + i y) = 2 \log(x + i y) =
   \log(x^2 + y^2) + 4 \arctan( y / (x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}). \,$
The trouble with using $\, v(x,y)=2 \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})+c \,$ is that
the constant $\, c \,$ depends on $\, x<0 \,$ or $\, x>0. \,$ The alternate
expression only has a problem when $\, x < 0 \,$ and $\, y = 0. \,$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac\pi2$. Therefore, $2\arctan\left(\frac xy\right)+2\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)$ is constant.

Comment: So what did I do wrong in my solution? :)

Comment: ...but it's a different constant for $y/x < 0$ vs $y/x > 0$.

Comment: @WinstonCherf I suppose that the original question said something about the domain of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, It did. We took Im(z)>0

Comment: @WinstonCherf So, $y$ is always greater than $0$, whereas $x$ can be $0$. So, the solution with $\arctan\left(\frac xy\right)$ is clearly a better one.